# Splitting a huge file into smaller files

Tags: tcl

How can I split a huge file into *n* number of smaller files using Tcl? The file name to split and number of files to be created have to be given through command line. Here is what I have so far:

```
proc splitter { file no } {
  set lnum 0
  set file_open [open $file r]
  while {[gets $file_open line] >= 0 } {
    incr lnum
  }
  puts "$lnum"
  set num [expr $lnum/$no]
  close $file_open
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to split text files, which has the advantage of not holding much in memory at once. (You can also split binary files, but then you need to use `read` instead of `gets`, and also to consider whether there are record boundaries in the data; text is mostly simpler.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh8.5
proc splitter {filename fileCount} {
    set targetFileSize [expr {[file size $filename] / $fileCount}]
    set n 0
    set fin [open $filename]
    while {[gets $fin line]} {
        if {![info exist fout]} {
            set fout [open $filename.split_[incr n] w]
        }
        puts $fout $line
        if {[tell $fout] > $targetFileSize} {
            close $fout
            unset fout
        }
    }
    if {[info exist fout]} {
        close $fout
    }
    close $fin
}
splitter {*}$argv;   # Connect to outside command line
```

Comment: This splits by approximate file size, not line length, but when lines are all of a similar length the difference is minimal and it means you can do this all in a single pass.

Answer (score 2):

- use the global `argv` array to access command line parameters
- after you read the file to count the lines, instead of closing the file handle, you can [`seek`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/seek.htm) back to the top of the file.
- if you're on *nix, have you considered using [`exec`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm) to call out to [`split`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split)?